# Cannot insert email to wordpress database

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, email

I am trying to insert a  email into the database. All other values except email gets posted. '0' is being inserted into the database instead of email id.

```
$wpdb->bloodregistration = $wpdb->prefix.'bloodregistration';
$wpdb->insert( $wpdb->bloodregistration,array( 'name' => $_POST['myname'], 'myemail' =>         $mailid,'age' => $_POST['age'],'gender' => $_POST['gender'],'location' => $_POST['location']
    ,'address' => $_POST['address'],'phone_land' => $_POST['ph_land'],'phone_mob' =>     $_POST['ph_mobile'],'blood_group' => $_POST['blood_group']
    ,'dob' => $dob,'lastblooddate' => $doblood),array('%s','%d') );
```

Answer (score 0):

What DB do you use? My guess is that you forgot to assign sequence/serial/auto-increment to ID column.

EDIT:

So the problem was this part `'myemail' =>         $mailid` you were inserting empty or not set variable into this field and therefore you got 0 in DB.

In DB set the column "myemail" to auto-increment, NOT NULL and INDEX PRIMARY.
Then in PHP simply skip this field when adding new records, DB will auto-increment it.

Try:

```
$wpdb->bloodregistration = $wpdb->prefix.'bloodregistration';
$wpdb->insert( $wpdb->bloodregistration,array( 'name' => $_POST['myname'],'age' => $_POST['age'],'gender' => $_POST['gender'],'location' => $_POST['location']
    ,'address' => $_POST['address'],'phone_land' => $_POST['ph_land'],'phone_mob' =>     $_POST['ph_mobile'],'blood_group' => $_POST['blood_group']
    ,'dob' => $dob,'lastblooddate' => $doblood),array('%s','%d') );
```

Comment: I am using mysql. So auto increment is needed? All other values are getting inserted.

Comment: Yes, set ID column to auto-increment, and leave it empty when inserting new records, DB will auto-generate proper number. Also set it to NOT NULL.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Let me try that.

Comment: Still it's not working. The email field is being inserted as '0'.

Comment: Be precise, what field do you mean? email, emailid, myemail, id? Show your DB structure.

Comment: The field in the database is 'myemail'. Every time when I insert from the wordpress page, all fields except the 'myemail' is getting inserted.

Comment: 'myemail' => $mailid, here's your problem. You are inserting $mailid variable to this field and I assume its value is 0 or NULL.